# EOS authentication

Tags: signin

I was wondering how users will "sign in" to EOS. Users will need to share some private keys with the web app if the user wants the app to interact on its behalf with the EOS blockchain. I believe this is how [steemit.com](https://steemit.com/) works.

EOS seems to have an advanced permission system, but I'm missing some guidance on best practices. I believe asking users to install an extension like Scatter will add a lot of friction, so I'm not considering it. Looking forward to knowing more about how this authentication & authorization mechanism will work.

Answer (score 14):

I agree in parts when you say that asking to install an extension is a "lot of friction"... But we are dealing with real money here: the EOS Tokens. People want to feel protected. Majority of ETH adopters have Metamask.

It reminds me of the beginning of the internet where we should have an email to signup an account, and as people didn't like that, websites started to create the annoying usernames, that eventually turns out such a pain in the ass because you always forget. Now every decent service asks for email and people are fine.

Well I think we need to **EDUCATE** people. Blockchain is a new topic and there's no other way around. Imagine when it get real traction and every single website utilizes Scatter identities: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=06RSj40bHhs

In a matter of 1 click you are logged in and most important **PROTECTED**.

In our project we are struggling about UX for a full new user signup flow: installation of Scatter, generation of keys, submitting it to our server to create and stake an eos account, make the user open scatter again and create a new identity... None of the stakeholders have liked it, so I'm working with a solution that we can improve a lil bit, trying to turn this process smoother...

But what I told them is that there's no other way around to get decentralized, people will really need to install a wallet to handle their accounts, does not matter if it's a desktop, mobile one, but honestly an extension like Scatter is amazing for that.

Unless you want to centralize and hold your users keys... Would you trust any app to do that? Or, you could even create an account for this app and only hold a minimum amount of tokens there... At the end you will end up with a lot of accounts (like usernames I mentioned above)...

Comment: You are probably right that this is the way to go. I just like how seamless steemit.com is, although I agree with you that this is a problem when you have "accounts" on many sites.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to enforce people to use any extension.

You can generate a private key directly in the browser and store it its localstorage encrypted over a password with https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs-keygen

When the user "logs in" to your app, it just is going to be recovery the private key back from the local storage. The key would never travel the internet.

When actually creating a new account for the user, you will send the generated PUBLIC key over to your server for signing the account creation transaction with your app's account.

In any case, seems reasonable to *support* people that has an existing EOS account and wallet integrating with Scatter.

-- EDIT --

For the question: what would happen if the user clears his localstorage?

You should always give them their private key and instruct them to store it in a safe place, and give the option to recover back from there by inputing the private key as a way of login. Additionally the accounts that you create could have your app account listed as 50% `owner` and you could instruct the user to set a friend as his account recovery with the other 50%, then he could recover his account completely even in the worse case by obtaining a transaction singed by both to "reset" his owner key.

Comment: That's an interesting workaround, although it would be bad to tell users that they are screwed if they ever clear the browser cache.

Comment: but how are you going to sign transactions and interact with the application?

Comment: localstorage is not a permanent solution, if the browsers cache is cleared this will go too. This is why most methods involve some sort of browser extension. Either you'll have to ask them to back it up properly, which creates friction or rely on a more robust method.

Comment: @altShiftDev, edited to add a comment regarding clearing cache.

Comment: @LeoRibeiro you can do all that from JS. In the end your app is always calling http methods

Comment: That I understand, but are you going to give your PK to the application when you need to sign a transaction? Let's say a simple one like comment or vote. When you have scatter you have a popup to confirm the transaction you are signing and the app never sees your PK.

Comment: Yeah. But that is a matter of trust and proper policy and communication. The private key must never travel the internet. For the case you also trust Scatter devs not to do whatever they want with your key. In any case I say that you should support it or any other competitors, just not lock in to it if you want to reduce friction

Comment: awwww man... You are absolutely right. I finally understood how eosjs-keygen works and yes, it's definitely a matter of policy and communication! Thank you for bring it up to my sight!

Answer (score 1):

I would agree Scatter or a similar application would be the best practice.  That said, it is undoubtedly going to cause friction for the end user.  Maybe I am missing something but why not offer both options:

- Authentication and Transaction Signing with Scatter

  or
- Authentication via traditional Username and password

The second option could be achieved by generating a Keystore File (UTC/JSON) encrypted with the users normal password. The keystore file could be safely stored on the blockchain (or in any other DB) and used to recreate their Private Key each time the User authenticates.  Furthermore if the user wanted to change their password in the future you could simply generate a new Keystore file associated with them.

This seems to be the way Scatter generates its backup file and the preferred way to authenticate in MyEtherWallet.

If people like this approach I will create an example and post to my GitHub

Comment: Thanks for the idea. As I see it, you still can derive the private key from the password, so this is not really improving security. You still are trusting the web app not to do unwanted things with your EOS account.

However, I see clear benefits in that the user needs to remember a password instead of an ugly private key and that the web app could be replicated and still be able to access the encrypted user credentials (since they could live in the blockchain instead of a traditional DB).

Comment: Yes, with traditional login the application can do unauthorized activity.  However, that is the case with all applications currently.  That is why I would advocate offering both options: 
Scatter for  Users who value security and 
Traditional Login for Users who value convenience

Answer (score 0):

You can always handle the 'sign in' as usual, it need not be a on-chain authentication method. Your db can handle the correlations between usernames and keys. These keys would hold 0 tokens and they never have to be shared with the user either.

However this seems like a lot of unnecessary work when Scatter solves all of this. If you want to create the best possible experience, offering both of these solutions would probably be ideal, let the user decide how they want to handle authentication.